# Comparing ranges of different groups

Tags: range

I have data that's like as follows

$A : 133-134$

$B : 131-135$

$C : 135-148$

I have to check if $A$ is more "similar" to $B$ or $C$ where similarity is defined as smallest "distance" between the initial and final points of the groups (the definition of "similarity" in this case is not absolute and can be changed if a better proposal is provided).

For example,

$Initial_{AB}= |133-131|=2;$ $Final_{AB}= |134-135|=1$

$Initial_{AC}= |133-135|=2;$ $Final_{AC}= |134-148|=14$

Thus by adding the values, we can figure out that $AB$ are more similar than $AC$.

Now we see that $A$ and $B$ are much more similar than $AC$. Is there an appropriate statistical test for such analysis?

Comment: If your similarity metric is already defined as you did I do not see any other way to solve the problem other than the way you already did.

Comment: But I am not able to come up with a rigorous definition of the stated test so I could use it in a research paper. It would be very helpful if you could direct me to a source which has discovered the metric in greater detail.

Comment: I will suggest a rank test, but that will mean we can no longer use your similarity definition.

Comment: Can you suggest which test would be suitable, since there are various kinds of rank test, given that I have only 3 data plots?